On the path, through the path
When I use "path" in a sentence, I am used to adding on before it.
For instance,

The path on which I traveled...

Recently, I came across something like

The mountainous path through which he traveled

If I were to write, I would have written it as

The path running through/along the mountains on which he traveled

But the other way reads nicer and shorter. However, is it correct to use through with path?

Both prepositions are just metaphors - on refers to stepping across / along a surface, where through suggests flowing inside a pipe / conduit

If you want short and clean: The path I traveled. On which adds no information.

Adding to FumbleFingers' comment, I would not say travel through the mountainous path. I would describe the travel as on/along the path, and through the mountains/mountainous area.

@PeterKirkpatrick: We tend to walk across a [featureless] desert, but it's run through the jungle. Where Credence Clearwater were just reflecting normal preposition usage. If you're often surrounded by head-high or taller things (trees, vines) as you travel, you're more likely to say you're traveling through it. If you can see just miles of sand in every direction, it's the kind of terrain you travel across or over.


The mountainous path through which he traveled

I borrow @FumbleFingers pipe/ conduit metaphor, which is a great tool to help us imagine: The path is under thick cover of overgrowth throughout its length so much that it looks like a pipe or conduit.

Sometimes we might use through for a mountain path even if there's no vegetation at all - just bare rock. That's because mountain paths usually follow the "lowest" practical route, going through mountain passes, rather than over mountain peaks. Just as you might travel through a canyon where you're surrounded by rock, not trees.

Good search.  Thanks, FF.

I just thought of another one. Jesus might have walked on water, but most of us wade through water and trudge through snow, even if it's only a few inches deep. Any route where somethng impedes progress tends to get through rather than on, across, along, over,...

Yes. Through is good for any route where something impedes progress. Sense 3c says used as a function word to indicate exposure to a specified set of conditions.

@FumbleFingers In case of a mountain pass, it clearly has barriers making it difficult for travelers. So, through works well with it. When it is a mountain path, it is still a path; unless the path is further defined explicitly, as one with lots of barriers, using through doesn't sound apt to me.

@Ammu: I suggest you read some of these written examples until it does sound appropriate (not "apt").
